# Eigenvalue problem with asymmetric boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the unit square $\,\Omega = (0,1) \times (0,1) $ and the normal eigenvalue problem for Laplace's equation
$$
-\Delta u = \lambda u
$$
with the boundary conditions that on the vertical sides of the square and on the bottom of the square $$u = 0$$
and on the top of the square $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$$ where $n$ is the outward normal.  I have come up with the answer $\sin{\pi k x_1} \, \sin{\frac{\pi k}{2} x_2}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda = \pi^2 k^2 + \frac{\pi^2k^2}{4}$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$.  However, the question asks to show that the eigenvalues are the roots of the equation $s - \tan s = 0$, but I plugged my solution into wolfram and it matches all the boundary conditions and solves the PDE.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I see where the error is, where you have $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x_2)$, what you should have is $(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$

Overall resulting in $\lambda_k=\pi^2k^2+(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)^2=\pi^2k^2+\frac{\pi^2}{4}+k\pi^2+k^2\pi^2=\frac{\pi^2}{4}+k\pi^2+2k^2\pi^2$.

Check your working and you will see that for $k=0$, $\alpha=0$ does not give you a non trivial solution for $X_2(x_2)$.

Comment: Oh I see.  Is $\frac{\pi^2}{4} + k\pi^2 + 2k^2\pi^2$ the solution to the equation $s -\tan s = 0$?

Comment: @user137302
it is not quite! but I may have made mistakes, go back to your eigenvalues, taking into account the correction  have put, and tell me what happens, I feel we are close to the desired result

Comment: I have seen situations similar to this, but it required $du/dn=0$ on the top and bottom boundaries, are you sure that is not the case here?

Comment: I have checked, and it definitely solves the PDE, but not $\tan(s)=s$ which is very strange.

Comment: Just looking into it, the boundary conditions that cause this situation are exactly the same but it should be $du/dn+u=0$ on the upper boundary.

Comment: There must be a typo in this problem.  Ok so in the case you described, do you need both sine and cosine terms that cancel at y = 1 and whose derivatives cancel at y=1 as well?

Comment: we need to end up with the situation $\sin(\alpha )-\alpha\cos(\alpha )=0\Rightarrow\tan(\alpha)=\alpha$, this occurs if at $y=1$, $Y'(1)+Y(1)=0$, which I believe corresponds to $du/dn+u=0$ on the top boundary.

Comment: Okay so I think I know the boundary conditions that would give us this situation, and they are $Y'(0)+Y(0)=0,Y(1)=0$

Comment: Ok thanks.  My professor wrote the question and I'm guessing he must have messed up the boundary conditions on the problem, I'll shoot him an email and ask.

Comment: yeah seems like it, since your solution definitely holds so it must be the BC's but as you can imagine, it's quite tricky to make up BC's that do what you want them to!